# NGVD 29 undulation layer

Tags: geospatial

I am looking for NGVD 1929 undulation layer. So that I can convert my vertical datum from NGVD 1929 to WGS 1984. I was able to get EGM 2008 undulation layer in GeoTiff format. I was hoping to get the same for the NGVD 1929.